# $IC(U\cap V)$ VS $IC(U)\cap IC(V)$

Tags: general-topology, modal-logic

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $U,V\subseteq X$ any subsets of $X$ .

Let $I(A)$ denotes a interior of subset $A$ and $C(A)$ denotes closure of subset $A$.

It is clear that $IC(U\cap V)\subseteq IC(U)\cap IC(V)$

Because $U\cap V\subseteq U$ and $U\cap V\subseteq U$

then $C(U\cap V)\subseteq C(U)$ and $C(U\cap V)\subseteq C(V)$;

then $IC(U\cap V)\subseteq IC(U)$ and $IC(U\cap V)\subseteq IC(V)$ ;

then $IC(U\cap V)\subseteq IC(U)\cap C(V)$.

In terms of modal logic $S4: \Box \Diamond(\Box p\wedge \Box q)\rightarrow\Box\Diamond \Box p\wedge \Box \Diamond \Box q$

Now let $U,V\in \tau$ aere two open sets of $X$.

Is it true another direction: $IC(U)\cap IC(V)\subseteq IC(U\cap V)$? (In terms of modal logic $S4: \Box\Diamond \Box p\wedge \Box \Diamond \Box q\rightarrow \Box \Diamond(\Box p\wedge \Box q)$)

If it is, what will be the proof of this?

If it isn't what is counterexamlpe of this?

Comment: Yes. This holds for open sets. A proof is in Halmos' book on Boolean Algebras. I could write it down later, time permitting.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma Thank you. one more question, Is it in "Lectures on Boolean Algebras" or in "Introduction to Boolean algebras"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I last saw it via Google books.

Comment: Ok thanks once more I will look in  both books.

Comment: It's chapter 10 in Introduction to Boolean Algebras (Givant and Halmos), a continuation of chapter 9, which introduces the notations.

Comment: Yes I also have found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is true more general fact.**

**Proposition.** If $U$ is open and $A$ an arbitrary subset of $X$, then $IC(U)\cap IC(A)\subseteq IC(U\cap A)$.

> **Proof**. Suppose $$x\in IC(U)\cap IC(A)$$.
>   $x\in IC(U)\cap IC(A)$ iff there exists $U'$ an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $U'\subseteq C(U)\cap C(A)$.
>
> Let us denote  $$U'\cap U=V_1$$ and $$U'\cap A=V_2.$$
>   $$U'\subseteq C(U'\cap C(U))\subseteq C(U'\cap U)=C(V_1)$$
>   $$U'\subseteq C(U'\cap C(A))\subseteq C(U'\cap A)=C(V_2)$$
>   $$U'\subseteq C(V_1)=C(U'\cap U)=C((U'\cap U)\cap U') \subseteq C((U'\cap U)\cap C(V_2))= \ = C((U'\cap U)\cap C(U'\cap A))\subseteq C((U'\cap U)\cap (U'\cap A))=C(V_1 \cap V_2)$$
>   We get 
>   $$U'\subseteq C(V_1 \cap V_2)=C(U'\cap (U\cap A))\subseteq C(U\cap A)$$ 
>   then 
>   $$x\in IC(U\cap A).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space with interior operator $I$ and closure operator $C$.

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$.

For convenience lets make the following notations: $C(A)=^{def}A^{-}$ and $X\backslash A=^{def}A'$

There is conjugation $I(A)=X\backslash (C(X\backslash A))=(( A') ^{-})'$.
We will need two following lemas.

**Lemma 1**: Let $A$ be a subset of $X$, then $IC(IC(A))=IC(A)$.

> **Proof**: Direction right to left:$$IC(A)\subseteq C(IC(A))$$ By monotonicity of interior and openness of $IC(A)$ $$IC(A)=I(IC(A))\subseteq I(C(IC(A)))=IC(IC(A)).$$ 
>   Direction left to right: $$I(C(A))\subseteq C(A)$$ By monotonicity of closure and closeness of $C(A)$ $$C(IC(A))\subseteq C(C(A))=C(A)$$ By monotonicity of interior $$IC(IC(A))\subseteq IC(A).$$

**Lemma 2**: Let $A,B$ are subsets of $X$, if $A$ is open then $A\cap C(B)\subseteq C(A\cap B)$.

> **Proof**: $ x\in A$ and $x\in C(B)$ iff $x\in A$ and for arbitrary $U_x$ an open neighborhood of $x$  $U_x \cap B\neq \emptyset$. Then for arbitrary $U_x$ an open neighborhood of $x$  $U_x \cap A\neq \emptyset$ is open neighborhood of $x$ and then  $U_x \cap A\cap B\neq \emptyset$, iff $x\in C(A\cap B)$.

Now let us prove the main result:

**Theorem**: If $U,V$ are open subsets of $X$, then $IC(U)\cap IC(V) \subseteq IC(U\cap V)$.

> **Proof**: $U$ is open, then by Lemma 2
>    $$U\cap V^{-} \subseteq (U\cap V)^{-}$$ 
>   By complementing this relation 
>   $${(U\cap V)^{-}}' \subseteq U' \cap {V^{-}}'$$ 
>   $${{(U\cap V)^{-}}'}^{-} \subseteq {U'}^{-} \cup {{V^{-}}'}^{-}$$ 
>   By complementing once more we get 
>   $$[{U'}^{-}]' \cap [{{V^{-}}'}^{-}]' \subseteq [{{(U\cap V)^{-}}'}^{-}]' $$
>   Notice that $U=(( U') ^{-})'$, then we get
>   $$U \cap [{{V^{-}}'}^{-}]' \subseteq [{{(U\cap V)^{-}}'}^{-}]'$$ 
>   For convenience lets denote $(A^-)'$ by $A^{\bot}$ we get $$U \cap V^{\bot\bot} \subseteq (U\cap V)^{\bot\bot}$$
>   Now put $U^{\bot\bot}$ in place of $U$, $U^{\bot\bot}$ is open
>   $$U^{\bot\bot} \cap V^{\bot\bot} \subseteq (U^{\bot\bot}\cap V)^{\bot\bot}$$ 
>   $V$ is open, then $U^{\bot\bot}\cap V\subseteq (U\cap V)^{\bot\bot}$ and then $(U^{\bot\bot}\cap V)\subseteq (U\cap V)^{\bot\bot\bot\bot}$ 
>   $$U^{\bot\bot} \cap V^{\bot\bot} \subseteq(U^{\bot\bot}\cap V)\subseteq (U\cap V)^{\bot\bot\bot\bot}$$
>   Now notice that $A^{\bot\bot}=IC(A)$, after rewriting and using Lemma 1 we get 
>   $$IC(U)\cap IC(V)\subseteq IC(IC(U\cap V))=IC(U\cap V).$$

Comment: $A$ still needs to be open (or use the rationals, irrationals example) in lemma 2. And make clear where you use the lemmas.

Comment: Oh, yes thank you. I have changed The lemma and proof.